# How might one toggle between multiple separate Flask applications that share the same structure and are in the same repo?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, containers, microservices

Apologies for not having a pithier way to explain that...tl;dr the best real-world example of what I'm looking for is Slack's team-switching functionality, wrt going from one team to an entirely different one while remaining in the same window and saving session data.

In case you'd like more context: essentially, I have been working on a organizational/note-taking tool for myself, comprised of template data structures (Entities, Categories, Collections, and Tags). For example, in my bookmark manager, I would use the Entities to represent my bookmarks, the Category to group by documentation/tutorial/etc., the Collections to group by my projects/skills involved/etc. And then I'd like to be able to interact with my bookmark manager through an interface, organize based on whatever query I feel like (e.g. 'search by tag:data-science' or 'search collection:projects by category'), and even take notes within the app. I'd like to repeat this same process with a separate app that I would use to take notes/structure course material, and another one for organizing my Spotify playlists, and so on. It may sound a bit silly, but it's how I'd like to organize my bookmarks and lists, because the hierarchical/nested structure just doesn't cut it for me.

I'm thinking that I should deploy this in one package and just essentially create a bunch of factory apps, because it seems like I'll be reusing the same code over and over again since I plan to keep the same templates for the apps and data structures (e.g. I plan to extend a base Entity class with specific attributes depending on the app). And if I'm doing that, then I like the idea of having all of this in one repository, where I could switch between the separate apps via an entry point that behaves like Slack's does. But I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I'm visualizing one central login that allows you to toggle between multiple apps depending on which one you're logging into, but maybe that's unrealistic/too grandiose. I'm reading into containerization a la Docker as well as [application dispatching patterns](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appdispatch/) but these seem like they work best for apps that are very different/independent or even meant to interact directly, whereas I expect my apps to share much of their templates/configuration. But perhaps I'm misinterpreting?

I would appreciate any nudge in the right direction, even a small one. :)

Comment: You could look into Docker compose. In that way, you can have a bunch of Flask containers running in the same pod, and an nginx container could proxy you between the different apps